# Webforms combine aspx code with data bounded data

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

in my webforms project I am using a data-bound repeater, and inside the item template of that repeater I am doing this to generate td's for my table.

```
<%
    For day as integer = 1 to DaysInMonth

%>

<td><img id='id_<%day.ToString()%>'/></td>

<% Next %>
```

What I need to do is to combine my integer value "day" and a value that is data-bound to the repeater. However, whatever I do I can't get them to interact.

If I use <%#> it doesn't recognize the variable day, and I also can't access the data bound value inside the <%%> code tags either.

Any advice on how to use a combination of values in <%%> and <%#> tags to get a certain data attribute? I am trying to determine if a task on a specified day is mark as "Completed" by the user, using a database lookup that requires task_id and day.

The day is a value in the <%%> tag and the Task_ID I use to grab task status is found in the data bound to the repeater.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have a way that works but it's not pretty

```
<%# RenderHTML(Eval("Task_Id"))%>
```

RenderHTML function returns the generated html string.